# How do I render ngIf without manually refreshing?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-ng-if

In a Todo App, I try to toggle with child routing between the preview of the todo and the edit mode for this specific todo. I use *ngIf

I expected that I will have a list of todos previews.
In "Edit" mode one of the todo-preview will be the edit-todo component and will allow editing the chosen todo.
After saving the edit it will render the preview todos along with the updated todo.

Result: After editing the todo it route back to preview all todos but the edited updated tood disappear.
Only after Browser refresh ( F5 ) updated todo shows along with all the todos.

I tried:

1. Tried doing it without *ngIf it works but I see in edit mode both of the edit todo and the preview todo.
2. I tried using [hidden]. Same results as *ngIf.

This is the Template of todo-preview:

```
<div class="todo-preview-container">
    <div class="preview-ctr" *ngIf="!isEditTodo; else editRoute">
        <ul class="todo-preview"  class=" todo {{ (todo.isDone ? 'done' : '') }}">
            <a [routerLink]="['/edit/',todo._id]" class="todo-content" (click)="isEditTodo=!isEditTodo">
                <li>{{todo.title}}</li>
            </a>
            <li class="todo-date">Created: {{todo.date | date:'short' }}</li>
            <li (click)="ontoggleCompleted()" class="todo-status">status: <span>{{todo.isDone ? "Done" : "Active"}}</span></li>
            <li class="todo-importance">Level: {{todo.importance}}</li>
            <!-- remove btn -->
        </ul>
        <button (click)="onIdToRemove.emit(todo._id)"></button>
    </div>
    <ng-template #editRoute>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </ng-template>
</div>
```

Comment: It would really help, if you could load your code on the starkblitz.